# I send a date from Angular and in c# I get a default date of datetime

Tags: c#, angularjs, model-view-controller

I send a date by Angular and also in C# but I get an unintended default date from datetime. For example if I send `05/06/2022` in C# I get `{01/01/0001 00:00:00}`.

How do I get the date I sent?

Comment: Send it in an ISO8601 format.

Comment: If it doesn't work then you did it wrong. As you haven't shown us what you did, we can't tell you what's wrong with it. Vague descriptions are not sufficient. Details are required.

Comment: Please improve your question by following the instructions on [ask].

Answer (score 0):

```
    $scope.ExportDataSetOrdersByOrderDate = function (dtDateOrder) {
        dtDateOrder = dtDateOrder.toString();
        let day = (dtDateOrder.split('/')[0]);
        let month = (dtDateOrder.split('/')[1])-1;
        let year = (dtDateOrder.split('/')[2]);
        let dateToSent = new Date(year, month,[day], ["00"], ["00"], ["00"], ["00"]);
```